# После обновления столбца в MS SQL с null на not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Был столбец:

```
[Address] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL
```

через скрипт обновил,

```
ALTER TABLE
  CNAP
ALTER COLUMN
  Address
    NVARCHAR(250) NULL;
```

Стало:

```
[Address] [nvarchar](250) NULL
```

После попытки вставить в этот столбец Null, выкидывает ошибку что этот столбец не поддерживает Null значения. Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit) 2012 v11.0.2100.60. В чем проблема?

Comment: Во-первых, надо бы указать сервер (и желательно версию). Во-вторых, неплохо бы указать, чем окончилось выполнение DDL-запроса.

Comment: Добавил версию. Запрос выполнился успешно

Comment: @JoraInTheSkyw Оформите как ответ

Comment: Это я один в упор не вижу разницы между "было" и "стало" в вопросе?

Comment: @Yaant Поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На таблице стоял триггер который и не давал обновлять/добовлять данные. После изменения триггера, все заработало как надо.